# Using jquery to refocus a user where they were typing within a series of form inputs

Tags: jquery, input, dialog, focus

I've been searching on this website as well as a few others for an answer to this question and while I've come up with a couple of things, I haven't found anything that quite fits my requirements.

I'm developing a form for use with a fundraising service in which people can engrave a message for stone pavers.  Since this is for a university, they want to be able to use greek letters in the forms.  I figured out a way to do this by catching when a user types a certain key (@) and opening a dialog box asking them to select a greek letter or cancel.  When they do, it replaces the @ with the greek letter that they chose (or "" if they just closed or canceled the dialog).

However, one of the biggest problems I've been having is that after this point, the focus is lost and the user is confused.  I want to return the focus to the exact place that it was before the dialog box opened.  Is that possible?

Here is the JS I'm using:

```
//giving form engraving greek letter replacement code
    var $greekLetters = $('<div class="greekModal"><ul><li><a href="#" class="close alpha"><img src="../../images/giving/alpha.gif" alt="Alpha" title="Alpha" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close beta"><img src="../../images/giving/beta.gif" alt="Beta" title="Beta" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close gamma"><img src="../../images/giving/gamma.gif" alt="Gamma" title="Gamma" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close delta"><img src="../../images/giving/delta.gif" alt="Delta" title="Delta" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close epsilon"><img src="../../images/giving/epsilon.gif" alt="Epsilon" title="Epsilon" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close zeta"><img src="../../images/giving/zeta.gif" alt="Zeta" title="Zeta" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close eta"><img src="../../images/giving/eta.gif" alt="Eta" title="Eta" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close theta"><img src="../../images/giving/theta.gif" alt="Theta" title="Theta" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close iota"><img src="../../images/giving/iota.gif" alt="Iota" title="Iota" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close kappa"><img src="../../images/giving/kappa.gif" alt="Kappa" title="Kappa" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close lambda"><img src="../../images/giving/lambda.gif" alt="Lambda" title="Lambda" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close mu"><img src="../../images/giving/mu.gif" alt="Mu" title="Mu" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close nu"><img src="../../images/giving/nu.gif" alt="Nu" title="Nu" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close xi"><img src="../../images/giving/xi.gif" alt="Xi" title="Xi" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close omicron"><img src="../../images/giving/omicron.gif" alt="Omicron" title="Omicron" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close pi"><img src="../../images/giving/pi.gif" alt="Pi" title="Pi" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close rho"><img src="../../images/giving/rho.gif" alt="Rho" title="Rho" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close sigma"><img src="../../images/giving/sigma.gif" alt="Sigma" title="Sigma" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close tau"><img src="../../images/giving/tau.gif" alt="Tau" title="Tau" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close upsilon"><img src="../../images/giving/upsilon.gif" alt="Upsilon" title="Upsilon" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close phi"><img src="../../images/giving/phi.gif" alt="Phi" title="Phi" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close chi"><img src="../../images/giving/chi.gif" alt="Chi" title="Chi" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close psi"><img src="../../images/giving/psi.gif" alt="Psi" title="Psi" /></a></li><li><a href="#" class="close omega"><img src="../../images/giving/omega.gif" alt="Omega" title="Omega" /></a></li></ul></div>')
    .dialog({   
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Select Greek Letter',
        modal: true,
        showCloseLabel: false,
        close: function(event, ui) { 
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"");
                    $( ".greekModal" ).dialog( "close" ); 
                    });
        },
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {

                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );

            } 
        }
        });

$(".greekModal a.alpha").click(function() {
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"Α");
                });
                return false;
});

$(".greekModal a.beta").click(function() {
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"Β");
                });
                return false;
});

$(".greekModal a.gamma").click(function() {
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"Γ");
                });
                return false;
});

$(".greekModal a.delta").click(function() {
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"Δ");
                });
                return false;
});

$(".greekModal a.epsilon").click(function() {
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"Ε");
                });
                return false;
});

$(".greekModal a.zeta").click(function() {
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"Ζ");
                });
                return false;
});

$(".greekModal a.eta").click(function() {
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"Η");
                });
                return false;
});

$(".greekModal a.theta").click(function() {
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"Θ");
                });
                return false;
});

$(".greekModal a.iota").click(function() {
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"Ι");
                });
                return false;
});

$(".greekModal a.kappa").click(function() {
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"Κ");
                });
                return false;
});

$(".greekModal a.lambda").click(function() {
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"Λ");
                });
                return false;
});

$(".greekModal a.mu").click(function() {
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"Μ");
                });
                return false;
});

$(".greekModal a.nu").click(function() {
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"Ν");
                });
                return false;
});

$(".greekModal a.xi").click(function() {
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"Ξ");
                });
                return false;
});

$(".greekModal a.omicron").click(function() {
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"Ο");
                });
                return false;
});

$(".greekModal a.pi").click(function() {
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"Π");
                });
                return false;
});

$(".greekModal a.rho").click(function() {
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"Ρ");
                });
                return false;
});

$(".greekModal a.sigma").click(function() {
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"Σ");
                });
                return false;
});

$(".greekModal a.tau").click(function() {
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/@/,"Τ");
                });
                return false;
    });

    $(".greekModal a.upsilon").click(function() {
                    $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                        return val.replace(/@/,"Υ");
                    });
                    return false;
    });

    $(".greekModal a.phi").click(function() {
                    $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                        return val.replace(/@/,"Φ");
                    });
                    return false;
    });

    $(".greekModal a.chi").click(function() {
                    $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                        return val.replace(/@/,"Χ");
                    });
                    return false;
    });

    $(".greekModal a.psi").click(function() {
                    $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                        return val.replace(/@/,"Ψ");
                    });
                    return false;
    });

    $(".greekModal a.omega").click(function() {
                    $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                        return val.replace(/@/,"Ω");
                    });
                    return false;
    });

    $(".greekModal a.close").click(function() {
                    $( ".greekModal" ).dialog( "close" );
                    return false;
    });

    if ($.browser.mozilla) { 
        $("input.engraving").keypress(function(event) {
            if(event.charCode == "64")
            {
                $greekLetters.dialog('open');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("input.engraving").keypress(function(event) {
            if(event.keyCode == "64")
        {
                $greekLetters.dialog('open');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The relevant html is:

```
<li><label class="desc" for="engraving_first_line">First Line: </label>
                        <input class="engraving" type="text" name="engraving_first_line" id="engraving_first_line" size="15" maxlength="15" /> (Maximum characters: 15)</li>
                    <li><label class="desc" for="engraving_second_line">Second Line: </label>
                        <input class="engraving" type="text" name="engraving_second_line" id="engraving_second_line" size="15" maxlength="15" /> (Maximum characters: 15)</li>
                    <li><label class="desc" for="engraving_third_line">Third Line: </label>
                        <input class="engraving" type="text" name="engraving_third_line" id="engraving_third_line" size="15" maxlength="15" /> (Maximum characters: 15)</li>
                    <li><label class="desc" for="engraving_fourth_line">Fourth Line: </label>
                        <input class="engraving" type="text" name="engraving_fourth_line" id="engraving_fourth_line" size="15" maxlength="15" /> (Maximum characters: 15)</li>
```

Comment: code will help us to see where the problem may be...

Comment: Why not store the input id that they were on last before opening the dialog ?

Comment: And then focus to that ID again, using spacing to place the cursor back where it was?  It's one of the ideas that I was looking at, but I'm not exactly sure how.

Comment: As for some of the code, I know I can simplify it into a defined function, I've just been focusing on making it work first then going back and cleaning up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('input').keydown(function(){
    $input = $(this); // Do this
    $('#greek').dialog({   
        close: function(event, ui) { 
            $input.val(function(i, val) { // And this
                $(this).focus(); // And this
                return val.replace(/@/,"");
                $('#greek').dialog('close'); 
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/PsqpV/

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the input element to the dialog and on closing the dialog call the `.focus()` on that element.

You can do something like this:

```
$("input.engraving").keypress(function(event) {
            if(event.charCode == "64")
            {
                $greekLetters.data('clickedInput', this).dialog('open');
            }
});
```

and in

```
.dialog({   
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Select Greek Letter',
        modal: true,
        showCloseLabel: false,
        close: function(event, ui) { 
                $("input.engraving").val(function(i, val) {
                    $(this).data('clickedInput').focus();
                    return val.replace(/@/,"");                        
        },
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).data('clickedInput').focus();
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );

            } 
        }
    });

    Cancel: function() {
                $(this).data('clickedInput').focus();
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );

    }
```

Comment: Hm, that's possible.  I have to figure out how to use it, but thank you.

Comment: I believe event.target will imply the dialog node, not the input node.